# How do I install Netbeans 9.0+?

Tags: java, netbeans

A lot has been changed since the release of Netbeans 9.0. Now Netbeans is taken by Apache Foundation. Also, APT still has v8.1 in Bionic Beaver (18.04). So, how do I install latest version (>9.0)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are basically 3 ways to install Apache Netbeans incubating as described below:

- **Installing using ubuntu-make**:

  Apache Netbeans (incubating) is now available via ubuntu-make. As they say, latest version, You can now install Netbeans 11.0 using ubuntu-make. For that, run:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
  umake ide netbeans
  ```
- **Installing from Binaries:**

  - For NetBeans 9.0: Download the binary zip for NetBeans 9.0 from [the direct download link](https://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-bin.zip).
  - For NetBeans 10.0: Download the binary zip for NetBeans 10.0 from [Apache Download Mirrors](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-10.0/incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin.zip)
  - For NetBeans 11.0: Download the binary zip for NetBeans 11.0 from [Apache Download Mirrors](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-11.0/incubating-netbeans-11.0-bin.zip)

    Unpack the zip and run `netbeans` in bin folder using `./netbeans`. I'll suggest to make a `desktop entry` a.k.a. menu shortcut. For details about it read [How can I create launchers on my desktop? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/64222/816190).
- **Building from Source:**

  **Note:** According to Apache NetBeans' release notes (which can be found on [Releases / Apache NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html#releases) under corresponding release) ***NetBeans 9.0 is compatible with JDK 8, 9 and 10***, ***NetBeans 10.0 with JDK 8, 9, 10 and 11*** and ***NetBeans 11.0 with JDK 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12***. Building NetBeans with an incompatible JDK might cause build errors. Moreover **JDK 9 and 10 were non-LTS** version of Java which seems to be **obsolete** as of now and are no longer available in Ubuntu's official repository. The installation process of both is described below.

  1. Download the source zip for:

     - NetBeans 9.0 from [the direct download link](https://archive.apache.org/dist/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-source.zip)
     - NetBeans 10.0 from [Apache Download Mirrors](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-10.0/incubating-netbeans-10.0-source.zip)
     - NetBeans 11.0 from [Apache Download Mirrors](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-11.0/incubating-netbeans-11.0-source.zip)
  2. Install either Oracle JDK or OpenJDK.

     - For Oracle JDK8: Download JDK8 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html) and run these commands:

       ```
       sudo su
       mkdir /opt/jdk
       tar -zxf jdk-8u181-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java 100
       update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java 100
       ```
     - For OpenJDK8, run

       ```
       sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
       sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
       ```
     - For OpenJDK11, run

       ```
       sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
       sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre
       ```
  3. Install Apache ANT: For installing Apache Ant, run

     ```
     sudo apt install ant
     ```
  4. Once you’re all set just extract the downloaded source, enter the incubator-netbeans directory and type `ant` to build the Apache NetBeans IDE.
  5. Once built, the IDE bits are placed in the `./nbbuild/netbeans` directory. You can run the IDE from within the incubator-netbeans directory by typing `./nbbuild/netbeans/bin/netbeans` or use `ant tryme` to run the Apache NetBeans IDE.

Answer (score 6):

**Apache NetBeans (incubating)** snap package can be installed from **Ubuntu Software Center** directly. The latest version is 11.0.

Comment: I don't know how it compares to `umake`, but this looks like the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans has been updated and NetBeans 10.0 can now be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install netbeans
```

This is the most convenient way to install NetBeans because there are also several NetBeans support libraries in the default Ubuntu repositories. You can list these packages with the following command:

```
apt search netbeans
```

The NetBeans version that I prefer in 18.04 however is the netbeans snap package which can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo snap install netbeans --classic
```

This command installs NetBeans 11.

Comment: In Ubuntu 19.04 use Ubuntu Software Center in order to install NetBeans 11.

The command "sudo apt install netbeans" installs the old version NetBeans 10 which does not work at my Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: @AndrewKrizhanovsky Ubuntu Software Center lists snap package which is v11 but APT still has v10. To install snap package via terminal, run `sudo snap install netbeans --classic`