# Can't install netbeans in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

I am encountering this error:

```
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/midori/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Comment: Netbeans is in the Universe repo of Ubuntu by default.  There should be no need to setup another PPA or Repo for Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problem while installing netbeans why don't you try this method:

1. Download this bash file from their official site

   ```
   wget -c http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```
2. Give executable permissions to the downloaded file

   ```
   chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```
3. Now execute this file and it will lead to install netbeans

   ```
   sudo ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
   ```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I want a latest version

Comment: just replace 8.2 in the above commands with the version you want to install or else this post might help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076408/how-do-i-install-netbeans-9-0-10-0

Comment: @RohitJadhav Mere "replacing 8.2 in the above commands with the version you want to install" isn't a solution. For 9.0 onward Apache mirrors are used.