# Need help with CLASSPATH I think

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to build the open source application found at: https://github.com/linklayer/cantact-app

I've installed netbeans and gotten to the point that I can create a new project.  I got help doing this via [Netbeans installed via APT opens but then closes, "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093498/netbeans-installed-via-apt-opens-but-then-closes-java-lang-noclassdeffounderro/1093681#1093681)

Now I'm still at a loss for how to set CLASSPATH in order to get the "ant build" command to work for cantact-app.  When I look at ~/.netbeans/8.2/var/log/messages.log, I don't see an actual "CLASSPATH".  Instead, I see a "Boot & Ext. Classpath", a "Application Classpath", and a "Startup Classpath". Well I took the value of "Application Classpath" and did an "export CLASSPATH=..." for that long path.  Now, "ant build" still gets a "BUILD FAILED" with message "Cannot find NetBeans build harness.  Check that nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir and nbplatform.default.harness.dir are defined..."

Answer (score 0):

### Synopsis

Netbeans have invalid values set for `nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir` and `nbplatform.default.harness.dir`. You can change these values either globally or locally.

### Global way

The default location for these `nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir` and `nbplatform.default.harness.dir` are usually located in the file `~/.netbeans/8.2/build.properties`

You can edit it with your favorite editor:
    gedit `~/.netbeans/8.2/build.properties`

Scroll down to the last line and you should see `nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir` and `nbplatform.default.harness.dir` keys. Change their values to this:

```
nbplatform.default.harness.dir=${nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir}/harness
nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir=/path/to/your/Netbeans/Folder/netbeans-8.2
```

*Note:* Write actual folder where your **Netbeans** is installed.

Save and exit.

Verify if the problem is solved.

### Local way (Making own default declarations):

1) Go to your project file default declarations (I suppose project name is `cantact-app-master`):

```
cd /path/to/Project/Folder/cantact-app-master/nbproject/private/
```

*Note:* Write actual folder where your **Project** is located.

Save and exit.

2) There should be some file called `platform-private.properties`, edit it with your favorite editor, otherwise create it:

```
gedit platform-private.properties
```

3) If in previous step, in case you edited it, you might encounter a line starting with a key `user.properties.file`. Anyways, comment it or if it is blank, write this:

```
user.properties.file=cd /path/to/**Project/Folder**/cantact-app-master/nbproject/private/build.properties
```

*Note 1:* Write actual folder where your **Project** is located.

*Note 2:* You can indicate `build.properties` wherever you want, but I assume that this is destination of this file.

Save and exit.

4) Create `build.properties` where you pointed `user.properties.file` key:

```
gedit build.properties
```

5) Add these lines:

```
nbplatform.default.harness.dir=${nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir}/harness
nbplatform.default.netbeans.dest.dir=/path/to/your/Netbeans/Folder/netbeans-8.2
```

*Note:* Write actual folder where your **Netbeans** is installed.

Save and exit.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks again, Olimjon.  Unfortunately, nothing matches up right.  For Global Way, I find four different "build.properties" files, and none of them have the text "dest.dir" in them.  I can't post an image.  So, from folder /usr/local/netbeans-8.2, I find files in ./harness/nbi/stub .  Below there is a build.properties directly, and ./ext/engine/build.properties, and ext/infra/build/products/helloworld/build.properties, and ext/infra/build/engine/build.properties.  To clarify, that last file mentioned is at /usr/loca/netbeans-8.2/harness/nbi/stub/ext/infra/build/engine/build.properties.

Comment: When I try the Local Way, I also run into trouble.  Project folder is ~/CANtact/cantact-app .  I find folder nbproject, but no "private" folder.  However, in nbproject, I do find platform.properties.  However, it doesn't have a user.properties.file.  It only has branding.token, cluster.path, disabled.modules, and nbplatform.active.